# Django Form request.POST.get() returns none value

Tags: html, django

Here is my Django

```
if request.method == 'GET':
     term = request.POST.get('term')
     grade = request.POST.get('grade')
     year = request.POST.get('year')
```

Here is my HTML code

```
                      <form method="GET">
                          <label><b>Term</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name='term'  id='term' placeholder="Ex:Term3">
                          <label><b>Grade</b></label>
                          <input type="text" name='grade' id='grade'  placeholder="Ex:Grade 11A">
                          <label><b>Year</b></label>
                          <input type="number" name='year' id="year" placeholder="Ex:2021">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{% url 'prediction'%} ">Search</a></button>
                     </form>
```

but term year and grade always show empty
Any one cam help me

Comment: Since the request method is GET, you obtain the data with `request.GET`, not `request.POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the request method is GET, you obtain the data with `request.GET`, not `request.POST`, so:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    grade = request.GET.get('grade')
    year = request.GET.get('year')
```

I would however advise to work with a (`Model`)`Form` to process the data, since a form performs validation, cleaning and removes a lot of boilerplate code.

You should also specify the URL to where the request is submitted in the `<form>` tag, so:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'prediction' %}">
    <label><b>Term</b></label>
    <input type="text" name='term'  id='term' placeholder="Ex:Term3">
    <label><b>Grade</b></label>
    <input type="text" name='grade' id='grade'  placeholder="Ex:Grade 11A">
    <label><b>Year</b></label>
    <input type="number" name='year' id="year" placeholder="Ex:2021">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Still same issue. I want to use value in Django scripts which are input in html

Comment: @SandaminiDasanayaka: it does not matter that you write a custom HTML form. A Django form does all sorts of tasks (besides *rendering* the form in HTML): it performs validation, cleaning and saving.

Comment: @SandaminiDasanayaka: can you `print(request.GET)` and `request.POST` and *edit* your question with the output.

Comment: Something strange is furthermore that you wrap the submit button in an `<a href=...>`?

Comment: @SandaminiDasanayaka: normally you sue the `<form action="...">` to specify where to "route" the HTTP request to.

Comment: <form method="GET"  action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/school/prediction">                             @Willem I use the above request in action, But now i cant move to the prediction

Comment: @SandaminiDasanayaka: that is why you can use a `{% url ... %}` in the `action="..."`, see edit.

Comment: @SandaminiDasanayaka: are you sure you are triggering the correct view, what is the ouput of `print(request.GET)` and `print(request.POST)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting your form values from `request.POST`.

your form method is `GET`:

so you should use `request.GET.get("whatever")`.

and if your form method is `POST`:

you should use `request.POST.get("whatever")`